# Java.Spring. BlockingQueue<>

Tags: java, spring

Я в спринге задаю бин

spring-app.xml

```
...
 <bean id="readControllerBlockingQueue"  class="java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue" />
...
```

Потом, в нужном мне классе я беру на него ссылку:

```
class Example1 {
...
@Autowired
private BlockingQueue readControllerBlockingQueue;
...
}
```

Я не могу понять, как мне в спринге объявить бин с "типизацией" объектов, которые будут через него передаваться?
Чтоб я мог привязать так:

```
class Example1 {
...
@Autowired
private BlockingQueue<myCustomClass> readControllerBlockingQueue;
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, с помощью XML это сделать невозможно, не делая при этом кастомные конфигурации, но ты можешь перенести конфигурацию из XML в JAVA примерно так:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig{

    @Bean
    public BlockingQueue<MyCustomClass1> readControllerBlockingQueue()
    {
    ....
    }

    @Bean
    public BlockingQueue<MyCustomClass2> anotherBlockingQueue()
    {
    ....
    } 

}
```

В этом случае spring (с версии 4.0) сможет распознать какой бин внедрять в такой объект:

```
class Example1 {
...
@Autowired
private BlockingQueue<MyCustomClass1> readControllerBlockingQueue;
...
}
```

P.S. учти, что если вместо `BlockingQueue` ты захочешь использовать `List`, `Set` или `Map`, то придётся дополнительно ещё что-то использовать, к примеру [@Qualifier](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html), т.к. такого рода внедрения он обрабатывает по-особому.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я решил пока оставить без "типизации". Нет желания из-за этого создавать конфигурацию еще в одном месте.